# Testing kernel Crypto API on linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, cryptography

I have a Freescale i.MX board on which I run the Linux 3.0.35 kernel.

I want to test if the Kernel Crypto API of my Linux system works. I just found out the test program is called `tcrypt`. I see that under `/lib/modules/` there is a `tcrypt.ko` in the `drivers` directory. This being the case, is there anyway I can test run this library? How do I call it? Do I need to reconfigure my kernel to "enable" something to call it?

Please keep in mind that I am new to kernel API's.

Comment: With just [tag:linux-kernel] and [tag:cryptography] your question does not have too many popular tags to be noticed. Make sure you maximize the exposure of your question (and please capitalize your sentences, read the FAQ!)

Answer (score 4):

I had to compile the kernel modules. This built the "tcrypt.ko" module too. Then I used "insmod" command to load the module. Once loaded, the module was started with :

```
modprobe tcrypt sec=1 mode=200
```

(where mode is the algorithm to test)